Pipeline variables not expanding in Docker build args
I am trying to pass today’s date to a Dockerfile using a —build-arg in the Azure DevOps Docker@2 task. However, whenever I pass the variable, it doesn’t expand.
I have a template file for variables and successfully use it elsewhere. It is TODAY:$(date ‘%Y-%m-%d’) and I can call it in most places with $(TODAY) and it prints out like 2024-09-03. However, in my Docker task, that never expands and I’ve tried every which way of sending it (as a parameter, variables, with and without quotes etc). E.g. —build-arg TODAY=$(TODAY), …=${{parameters.TODAY}}, …=${{variables.TODAY}}, …=$(date ‘%Y-%m-%d’) and so on.
Any ideas how I can achieve this?

When you set the variable: TODAY:$(date '%Y-%m-%d') and pass the variable to the docker task argument, it will not execute the date command to get the correct value. It will be treated as a string and pass to the dockerfile.
But when you use it in bash task, it will execute the date command and pass to the variable: Today.

I am trying to pass today’s date to a Dockerfile using a —build-arg in the Azure DevOps Docker@2 task.

I suggest that you can use the following  built-in expression: format to define the Today variable:
variables:
  TODAY: $[ format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]

Then you can pass the docker argument: -—build-arg TODAY=$(TODAY)
Full YAML sample:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
  TODAY: $[ format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime) ]
steps:
- bash: echo $(TODAY)
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    arguments: '--build-arg TODAY=$(TODAY)'

In this case, the TODAY variable will be set with the correct value before the docker task execute.
Result:
Dockerfile:
FROM node:8
ARG TODAY
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN echo ${TODAY}


